# Background Color for row in NSOutlineView

Tags: swift, macos, nsoutlineview

How do I set the background color for 1 particular row in an NSOutlineView? I have tried this with no luck:

```
func outlineView(_ outlineView: NSOutlineView, rowViewForItem item: Any) -> NSTableRowView? {
    let newRow = NSTableRowView()
    newRow.backgroundColor = NSColor.red
    return newRow
}
```

Answer (score 5):

What you need instead is `outlineView(didAdd:forRow)`. Here's what your code would look like:

```
func outlineView(_ outlineView: NSOutlineView, didAdd rowView: NSTableRowView, forRow row: Int) {
    rowView.backgroundColor = .red
}
```

Note that unlike most other `outlineView` delegate methods, `outlineView(didAdd:forRow)` gives you a row index instead of an `item`. You can get the item by calling `outlineView.item(atRow: row)`.

The reason your code didn't work is that `outlineView(rowViewForItem:)` creates the `NSTableRowView` before any styling is applied. The styling you were applynig there was being overwritten `outlineView` applying its own styling. The method is meant to be used for subclassing `NSTableRowView`.